# How do I calculate the sum of Value for the last 6 sprints using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Problem:
I need a calculated measure in `DAX` that sums the Value column for the last 6 sprints. I am basing the last 6 sprints on the `DimSprintEndDateKey` in descending order.

*Table structure in PowerBI*
[image]

The DAX that I am using:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( factSprint[Value] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( factSprint ),
        COUNTROWS (

        topn(6,

            FILTER (
                factSprint,
                EARLIEST( RELATED ( dimSprint[DimSprintEndDateKey] ) )
                    > RELATED ( dimSprint[DimSprintEndDateKey] )
            ),RELATED ( dimSprint[DimSprintEndDateKey] ), DESC


            )

        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have both a fact and dimension table for your sprints?

Comment: The dimension data is coming from VSTS and the fact data is coming from multiple sources.   The client is providing the data and has not yet given us a way to tie the sources together.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the relationship on your tables is between `'dimSprint'[dimSprintKey]` and `'FactSprint'[dimSprintKey]`.

That being the case, this measure could work for you.

```
Total Value Last Six Sprints =
VAR endDateSprint =
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        'dimSprint'[dimSprintEndDateKey],
        'dimSprint'[dimSprintKey], SELECTEDVALUE ( 'FactSprint'[dimSprintKey] )
    )
VAR dimTableFiltered =
    FILTER ( 'dimSprint', 'dimSprint'[dimSprintEndDateKey] <= endDateSprint )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'FactSprint'[Value] ),
        ALL ( 'FactSprint' ),
        TOPN ( 6, dimTableFiltered, [dimSprintEndDateKey], DESC )
    )
```

Use it on a matrix visual (or pivottable). Be sure to put `'FactSprint'[dimSprintKey]` or `'FactSprint'[SprintPK]` on Rows and [Total Value Last Six Sprints] on Values.